# Displaying request results from backend to html (MEAN)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, express

Currently developing an angular app with a node.js + express backend. I have successfully requested the correct documents from mongoDB and am able to view these documents via terminal. My problem lies within getting that same data and displaying it to my html template. So far, this is what I have:

**`//api.js`**

```
router.get('/user/paPolicies/:id', (req, res) => {
    const myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
    var data = req.body;


    return db.collection('users').findOne(myquery, {paPolicies: 1})
    .then(result => {
        if(result) {
            console.log(result.paPolicies)
        } else {
            console.log('No document matches the provided query.')
        }
        return result;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`Failed to find document: ${err}`))
   
   
})
```

**`//users.service.ts`**

```
  getUserPaPolicies(_id: string, paPolicies: object) {
    return this.http.get(`./api/user/paPolicies/${_id}`, paPolicies)
  }
```

**`//user-view-portfolio.component.ts`**

```
export class UserViewPortfolioComponent implements OnInit {

  id: any;
  paPolicies: any = [];

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.id = this.authService.getUserId();
    console.log(this.id);

    this.usersService.getUserPaPolicies(this.id, this.paPolicies).subscribe(result => {
      this.paPolicies = result;
      console.log(result)
    });
   

  }

}
```

The code I've written as seen above is able to GET the document I've requested for. However, this data can only be viewed within the terminal. An important thing to note is that paPolicies is an array and if need be, I can edit this post to add the output for `console.log(result.paPolicies)`.

**The problem(s):**

1. The console.log within the component code does not even show any output when I view chrome dev tools console.
2. Apparently, if I remove this chunk of code from the component.ts:

   `this.usersService.getUserPaPolicies(this.id, this.paPolicies).subscribe(result => { this.paPolicies = result; console.log(result) });`

the terminal would stop showing the results of my request also.

How would I modify the code to be able to display the data in my html template?

Comment: How does your HTML template look so far?

Comment: What does this.authService.getUserId() look like..

Comment: this.authService.getUserId() is where during login, I'd set key value pair in the session if it is successful. I then would do a getUserId() to get the id of the user.

Comment: @LeBavarois my template looks like this:

`<p>user-view-portfolio works!</p>

<p>{{paPolicies}}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from not knowing how your HTML template in the Angular frontend looks like shouldn't you send a response instead of returning the result in order to send the data to the frontend?

```
router.get('/user/paPolicies/:id', (req, res) => {
const myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
var data = req.body;


return db.collection('users').findOne(myquery, {paPolicies: 1})
.then(result => {
    if(result) {
        console.log(result.paPolicies)
    } else {
        console.log('No document matches the provided query.')
    }
    // return result;
    res.send(result);
})
.catch(err => console.log(`Failed to find document: ${err}`))
```

})

Comment: oh my this makes a lot of sense. Let me try this and see if there's any difference.

Comment: hey @Lebavarois, `res.send(result)` did make my code able to display the output of the console.log from the frontend! Thanks for the help.